# Putting Byte value into NSDictionary [iOS]

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, image, arrays

I have a post web service, where I need to send image in byte array, and as I need to send post parameters in JSON format, I have created its `NSDictionary`. My issue is how can I assign object to key in dictionary for `Byte`, I tried doing so and application crashes while creating `NSDictionary`. I am also explaining each steps with code for easy understanding of y question below :-

Here is my code for converting image to Byte format :-

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSUInteger len = [data bytes];
Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
memcpy(byteData, [data bytes], len);
```

So, now I have `Byte` which contain image in byte array, now I want to assign this object to `NSDictionary`. Here is code,

```
NSDictionary *dictJson = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
byteData, @"photo",
nil];
```

Now my application crashes in above line where I am creating `dictJson` object, is there any way I can pass Byte to `NSDictionary`?

Also, another question, how can I `NSLog` `byteData`?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My answer was right? You did not yet understand why your app going to crash!!! I faced problem, i doing lot of way for binary data. The real fact is When you try to create JSON object using NSDictionary all images should be in particular encoding format. Otherwise your app crash.

Comment: do you want to post data with image on server, right? and your data is in dictionary form?

Comment: @DipenPanchasara Yes, its in dictionary format for creating that dictionary to JSON for post request

Comment: @iAmbitious I already know how to use base64, but that is what I don't want, I want into byte array only..

Comment: See comment of @Martin R on each answer!!!!

Comment: NSData is the form of bytes, and your webservice also read that kind of data, NSData is binary form of value, and to send JSON you need to convert you dictionary to json using [jsonDict JSONRepresentation];

Comment: @P.J: If none of the answers helped so far, perhaps you could explain how the JSON should look like.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for your answer, I am getting error from web services, need some time to test your code. But anyways yours answer is what I was expecting, but dunno if its in that required format as required for web service..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to sent the image data as a JSON array containing the bytes as numbers,
then you have to create the array "manually", there is not built-in function:

```
NSData *data = ... // your image data
const unsigned char *bytes = [data bytes]; // no need to copy the data
NSUInteger length = [data length];
NSMutableArray *byteArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    [byteArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedChar:bytes[i]]];
}
NSDictionary *dictJson = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
              byteArray, @"photo",
              nil];
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictJson options:0 error:NULL];
```

The JSON data would then look like

```
{"photo":[byte0, byte1, byte2, ...]}
```

So perhaps that is what the server expects. But note that this is a very ineffective (in terms of space) way to send image data (compared to Base64 for example).

Answer (score 1):

If you'll send this information as JSON to a server, you need to convert it first to a valid string using an encoding such as [Base 64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Comment: I have already converted to Byte array and I dont want to use base64 as receiver needs image in byte array only..

Comment: If you want to send it inside a JSON text, you need to convert to base 64. Otherwise, you can set the request body to be the whole image and change its type.

Answer (score 0):

I believe any object you place in an `NSDictionary` must itself be derived from `NSObject`.

Clearly `Byte *` is not derived from `NSObject`.

Maybe try using a collection class that is, such as `NSArray`, or indeed try putting the `NSData` in there directly.

Comment: You cannot use NSData. NSJSONSerialization supports only NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull.

Comment: Other answers mentioned NSJSONSerialization, but the OP didn't.  I'm pretty sure you can put an NSData in an NSDictionary.  Google gives plenty of examples.

Comment: Yes, of course you can put NSData in NSDictionary. But JSON does not support data objects, and the question said *"... post parameters in JSON format ..."*

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the bytes into NSValue:

```
    UIImage* testImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
    NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(testImage);
    NSValue* value = [NSValue valueWithBytes:[data bytes] objCType:@encode(UIImage)];

    NSDictionary *dictJson = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              value, @"photo",
                              nil];
```

Comment: This will not work. NSJSONSerialization supports only NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull (but not NSValue).

Answer (score 0):

Create your Request Dictionary with File Object in it, later postWith: function will manipulate you image binding task

```
NSDictionary *requestDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"FirstObjectValue",@"FirstKey",
                             @"Second Object",@"Second Key",
                             @"myFileParameterToReadOnServerSide",@"file", nil]; // This line indicate ,POST data has file to attach
[self postWith:requestDict];
```

Following Function will read all your parameters from dictionary of objects you want to POST 
if you want to send image then add "file" key in your dictionary that identifies there is some file to be send with request

```
- (void)postWith:(NSDictionary *)post_vars
{
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YourHostString"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSString *boundary = @"----1010101010";

    //  define content type and add Body Boundry
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [post_vars keyEnumerator];
    NSString *key;
    NSString *value;
    NSString *content_disposition;

    while ((key = (NSString *)[enumerator nextObject])) {

        if ([key isEqualToString:@"file"]) {

            value = (NSString *)[post_vars objectForKey:key];
            //  ***     Write Your Image Name Here  ***
            // Covnert image to Data and bind to your post request
            NSData *postData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"], 1.0);

            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\";\r\nfilename=\"testUploadFile.jpg\"\r\n\r\n",value] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:postData];
        } else {
            value = (NSString *)[post_vars objectForKey:key];

            content_disposition = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", key];
            [body appendData:[content_disposition dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[value dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        }

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    }

    //Close the request body with Boundry
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", body.length] forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Length"];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", returnString);        
}
```