# How to convert json with data type of Byte to UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, byte

I am seeking for a help on how to convert a json value with data type of byte into an image. I don't have any idea of this.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896291/putting-byte-value-into-nsdictionary-ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I am assuming you have base-64 encoded form of image

```
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:strEncodeData options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no data type of "byte" in JSON. The data types are array, dictionary, string, number, bool and null. You might be getting a string with a base-64 encoded image. (You might get an array of numbers if the website developer is mad enough) Decode it to get an NSData object, pass that to the right UIImage initialiser.